How to preserve symbols under brackets?
Consider, e.g., a symbol =>. In Mathematica, it gets automatically converted into $\ge$. However, if I put the converted symbol inside the "" brackets (say, when I denote some plot legends, etc.), it gets converted back. Could you please tell me how to prevent this backward conversion?

You can use \[GreaterEqual], by pressing ESC > = ESC on the keyboard.

I cannot figure out how to convert ≥ back to >=. (I certainly don't expect it to convert to =>, which I suspect is a typo.) When I put it inside quotes "", it stays the same. Can you give an example of what you did?

Step advance your cursor to the "middle" of the symbol.
